# How can I add two or more model for a single view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a view page I want to add two models. One is for the Role-create and another for the Permissions-view.
It will also store in Role-Permission table (RoleID,PermissionID).

I've tried like below.

**model: Role-create**

```
public class Rolecreate
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Rolename", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]        
    public string Rolename { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Role description", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Roledescription { get; set; }

}
```

**controller: Role-create**

```
 // GET: /Role/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Role/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Role role)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Roles.Add(role);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Roles");
        }

        return View(role);
    }
```

**Model: Permission**

```
public partial class Permission
{
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }
    public string Permissionname { get; set; }
    public string Permissiondescription { get; set; }
}
```

But failed.

Please help me about this matter. 
Thank You

Comment: Create a view model containing 2 properties, one for Role and one for Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a model object that contains references to the objects you want ?

like

```
public class yourNewViewModel
{
    public RoleCreate model1 {get; set; }
    public Permissions model2 {get; set;}
}
```